# Can the same name fields of sub-class and parent-class exist independently in python?

Tags: python, inheritance

If my question is true, how to access the parent-class's same name field? Please complete the code.

```
# python 2/3
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()
        self.x = 2

    def getX(self):
        # how to code here ?
        super_x = None
        print("super.x={} Child.x={}".format(super_x, self.x))


Child().getX()
```

As a contrast, I also post the following java code snippet, and it can correctly run.

```
// java code
public class Parent {
    int x=1;
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    int x = 2;

    void getX() {
        System.out.println("super.x=" + super.x + " Child.x=" + x);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // output "super.x=1 Child.x=2"
        (new Child()).getX();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

I am simplifying and I might miss something, but:

When you execute `self.x = 1` in an instance method of a class that does not define `__setattr__`, `__set__` or `__slots__`, what ends up happening is `self.__dict__["x"] = 1`. An instance has only one `__dict__`, not one per parent class. No matter whether it is set in its own `__init__`, in a parent's `__init__` or anywhere else, it is always referencing the same location: the `"x"` key of the instance's `__dict__`. There's no "parent's same name field". If an `Animal` defines `colour` and `Dog` which inherits from `Animal` also mentions `colour`, for any given `fido` that is an instance of `Dog`, it only has one colour, not one for being an animal and one for being a dog.

Private fields, as discussed by Mr Fooz, get around this restriction by name mangling. For example, this code:

```
# python 2/3
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__x = 1

    def print_parent(self):
        print("Parent")
        print(self.__dict__)
        print(self.__x)


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()
        self.__x = 2
        self.print_parent()
        print("Child")
        print(self.__dict__)
        print(self.__x)

child = Child()
```

prints:

```
Parent
{'_Parent__x': 1, '_Child__x': 2}
1
Child
{'_Parent__x': 1, '_Child__x': 2}
2
```

Name mangling of `__x` into `_Parent__x` and `_Child__x` allows `__dict__` to contain both values without conflict, as two separate fields that are by convention treated as private though they are actually not:

```
print(child._Parent__x)
# => 1
print(child._Child__x)
# => 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you make the fields private, i.e. `self.__x` in your base class. The official Python tutorial has an excellent discussion of the topic. You can find it here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables